# jQuery DIV height issues

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, height, jquery-animate

Good day :)

I am using jQuery's animate() on both opacity and height, on a fixed-size div.
 It all works fine and dandy in firefox, but in IE8 (with and without compatibility-mode, so I am assuming it will have the same behavior in IE6 and IE7), the animation does show, but when the div height reaches 0%, the div's height adjusts to the height of the text inside of that div.
The first thing I immediately did was set overflow to hidden, but it still gives the same behavior.

I'm using the following function to slowly toggle height/opacity:

```
function OpacityFadeToggle(e_trigger, e_element, speed)
{
    $(e_trigger).toggle(
        function() {
            $(e_element).animate({ 
                opacity:    0.0,
                height:     "0px"
            }, speed);
        },
        function() {
            $(e_element).animate({
                opacity:    1.0,
                height:     "500px"
            }, speed);
        }
    );
}

$(function() {
    OpacityFadeToggle("a#a2", "div#b1", 1000);
});
```

Style for my "b1" div is the following:

```
div#b1 {
    color:      #ffffff;
    background-color:   #000000;
    overflow:       hidden;
    width:      600px;
    height:     500px;
    padding:        0px;
    margin:     0px;
    display:        block;
}
```

If you'd rather want to see a live example, I've temporarily set up a page over here: [click me!](http://93.125.207.114/jquery_tests)

Any help on this matter is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about animating it to 1px, then hiding the div after the animation is done?  Also, make sure to show the div again before animating from 1px to 500px.

```
function OpacityFadeToggle(e_trigger, e_element, speed)
{
    $(e_trigger).toggle(
        function() {
                $(e_element).animate({ 
                        opacity:        0.0,
                        height:         "1px"
                }, speed).hide();
        },
        function() {
                $(e_element).show().animate({
                        opacity:        1.0,
                        height:         "500px"
                }, speed);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Still a tiny little flicker, but not too bad.

Comment: Indeed still a tiny flicker but this should do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a callback to jQuery's animate call, and inside the callback hide the div by changing it's display property.

Comment: This results in the text 'Hi!' being flickering down to where it would normally rest and then back up to beside the link.